# How to count occurrence of word in a list using a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of words

```
words = ['two', 'forks.', 'one', 'knife.', 'two', 'glasses.','one', 
'plate.', 'one', 'naptkin.', 'his,' 'glasses.', 'his', 'knife.']
```

and need to count the occcurence of words using a dictionary like so.

```
word_counts = {'two':2, 'one':3, 'forks.':1, 'knife.':2, \
           'glasses.':2, 'plate.':1, 'naptkin.':1, 'his':2}
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = ['two', 'forks.', 'one', 'knife.', 'two', 'glasses.','one',
'plate.', 'one', 'naptkin.', 'his,' 'glasses.', 'his', 'knife.']

d = {}
for w in words:
    if w in d.keys():
        d[w] += 1
    else:
        d[w] = 1

print(d)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import Counter
words = ['two', 'forks.', 'one', 'knife.', 'two', 'glasses.','one', 'plate.', 'one', 'naptkin.', 'his,' 'glasses.', 'his', 'knife.']
dict(Counter(words))
```

Comment: Didn't know about counter - good one.

Comment: Little complex for what I've learned so far, but I'll keep this in mind for future use!

Comment: @Leonardo `Counter`s are dictionaries specialized for counting. You can just use them like regular dictionaries if all you need is to retrieve the word counts.

Comment: @LeonardoEcheverria it's an import and 1 line of code, far less complex than looping and manipulating dictionaries

Comment: `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, no need to convert.

Comment: @RoadRunner It's for the sake of output format

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is similar to that of Francky_V, but make use of the `.setdefault()` method. For example:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault('two', 0) # 'two' is not in d, we can set it 
0
>>> d.setdefault('two', 1000)  # 'two' is now in d, we cannot set it, returns current value
0
```

So, the solution:

```
d = {}
for word in words:
    d.setdefault(word, 0)
    d[word] += 1
```

The second solution makes use of `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for word in words:
    d[word] += 1
```

This works because `d` is a `defaultdict` with `int` for values. The first time we mention `d[word]`, the value is automatically set to `0`.

Of course, the `collections.Counter` is the best solution because that class is built for this purpose.